# Sign in without credit card if the Apple id is already created

Tags: itunes, macos, mac-appstore, apple-id

I have create my apple Id online using chrome and not from the App store or Itunes.
Now when i try to download any free app from the app store it gives me a error that the Apple id i am using has never been used before.
It takes me to a different page where i have to agree to the agreement and demands the credit card info on the next screen where the "none" option is not available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Log in Apple Store using your AppleID

Select Account

Select Edit for the Payment type

Select None.

[image: none]

Comment: There is no "none" option.

Comment: I have it showing! so what do you have ? in Apple Store app.

Comment: I have added some screenshots(extended the question)

Comment: OK, skip the Payment but fill out the Billing Address info. No worry they can not charge you anything.

Comment: I cant skip the payment info ,i need to fill it also

Comment: That sucks :(, maybe because you are in India ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The `none` option only comes for the US store. I have an Indian account for which I had to setup a credit card.

Answer (score 1):

Creation of Apple ID does not mean you've created an App store account, so when creating a App store account one you'll need to setup payment information either using a credit card or a debit card if you're creating an *Indian* Apple app store account. Payment setup is done to ease the process of buying content/apps later while using the store. The initial setup does not require you to make any payments.

`None` option for payment type is not available for the Indian users. It's been this way for a very long time. Although if you really had no other choice, You could create an apple account with US app store and select `None` as the payment choice.

Comment: Even after changing the location to US there is still no "none" option. Only "Paypal" has been added.

Comment: @Krill start over. Create a new apple store account. If you try to switch on the existing account, it does not appear usually.